# Awk merge the result of three files into a single file and delimit by any character

Tags: awk

I use awk to replace the space delimiter between each field so it becomes one field. I want to merge the output from processing any number of file into a resulting file, delimited by space.

```
awk -v OFS='^' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)printf("%s%s", $i,(i==NF)?ORS:OFS)}' filename > outputFile
```

File1 After Awk command

```
777^Brockton^Avenue,^Abington^MA^2351         
30^Memorial^Drive,Avon^MA^2322               
250^Hartford^Avenue,^Bellingham^MA^2019.    
....
```

When awk is applied to file 2 it is not affected by the command because it has only one field.

```
madanm@comcast.net
skajan@verizon.net
barnett@hotmail.com
sbmrjbr@sbcglobal.net
mastinfo@sbcglobal.net
....
```

I tried this to merge three files after it applies the awk command

```
paste listOf* |  awk -v OFS='^' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)printf("%s%s", $i,(i==NF)?ORS:OFS)}' > outputFile
```

But my result looks like this

```
777^Brockton^Avenue,^Abington^MA^2351^madanm@comcast.net^Manual^Ordway
30^Memorial^Drive,^Avon^MA^2322^skajan@verizon.net^Yuonne^Cajigas
250^Hartford^Avenue,^Bellingham^MA^2019^barnett@hotmail.com^Pattie^Darsey
700^Oak^Street,^Brockton^MA^2301^sbmrjbr@sbcglobal.net^Cammie^Knoles
66-4^Parkhurst^Rd,^Chelmsford^MA^1824^mastinfo@sbcglobal.net^Evia^Fallen
591^Memorial^Dr,^Chicopee^MA^1020^carcus@aol.com^Soo^Sanfilippo
```

I want it to look like this

```
Home Address[delimiter]Email[delimiter]Name[delimiter]

777^Brockton^Avenue,^Abington^MA^2351 madanm@comcast.net Manual^Ordway
30^Memorial^Drive,^Avon^MA^2322 skajan@verizon.net Yuonne^Cajigas
250^Hartford^Avenue,^Bellingham^MA^2019 barnett@hotmail.com Pattie^Darsey
700^Oak^Street,^Brockton^MA^2301 sbmrjbr@sbcglobal.net Cammie^Knoles
66-4^Parkhurst^Rd,^Chelmsford^MA^1824 mastinfo@sbcglobal.net Evia^Fallen
591^Memorial^Dr,^Chicopee^MA^1020 carcus@aol.com Soo^Sanfilippo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do what you're trying to do, you're really messing up your files. In particular `^` is a terrible choice of a character to introduce since it's a regexp metachar and so would make any further processing much more difficult than it has to be. Why not just leave the blank chars in the input alone (convert any tabs in them to spaces if tabs could be present) and use tabs as separators or convert the whole thing to CSV?

For example given this input:

```
$ cat file1
777 Brockton Avenue, Abington MA 2351
30 Memorial Drive, Avon MA 2322
250 Hartford Avenue, Bellingham MA 2019
700 Oak Street, Brockton MA 2301
66-4 Parkhurst Rd, Chelmsford MA 1824
591 Memorial Dr, Chicopee MA 1020

$ cat file2
madanm@comcast.net
skajan@verizon.net
barnett@hotmail.com
sbmrjbr@sbcglobal.net
mastinfo@sbcglobal.net
carcus@aol.com

$ cat file3
Manual Ordway
Yuonne Cajigas
Pattie Darsey
Cammie Knoles
Evia Fallen
Soo Sanfilippo
```

you can produce TSV:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = "\t"
    ofmt = "%s%s"
    numFiles = ARGC - 1
}
FNR == 1 {
    fileNr++
}
{
    gsub(/[[:space:]]+/," ")
    gsub(/^ | $/,"")
    val[FNR,ARGIND] = $0
}
fileNr == numFiles {
    for (i=1; i<=numFiles; i++) {
        printf ofmt, val[FNR,i], (i<numFiles ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2 file3
777 Brockton Avenue, Abington MA 2351   madanm@comcast.net      Manual Ordway
30 Memorial Drive, Avon MA 2322 skajan@verizon.net      Yuonne Cajigas
250 Hartford Avenue, Bellingham MA 2019 barnett@hotmail.com     Pattie Darsey
700 Oak Street, Brockton MA 2301        sbmrjbr@sbcglobal.net   Cammie Knoles
66-4 Parkhurst Rd, Chelmsford MA 1824   mastinfo@sbcglobal.net  Evia Fallen
591 Memorial Dr, Chicopee MA 1020       carcus@aol.com  Soo Sanfilippo
```

or CSV (only the values of `OFS` and `ofmt` are changed):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = ","
    ofmt = "\"%s\"%s"
    numFiles = ARGC - 1
}
FNR == 1 {
    fileNr++
}
{
    gsub(/[[:space:]]+/," ")
    gsub(/^ | $/,"")
    val[FNR,ARGIND] = $0
}
fileNr == numFiles {
    for (i=1; i<=numFiles; i++) {
        printf ofmt, val[FNR,i], (i<numFiles ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2 file3
"777 Brockton Avenue, Abington MA 2351","madanm@comcast.net","Manual Ordway"
"30 Memorial Drive, Avon MA 2322","skajan@verizon.net","Yuonne Cajigas"
"250 Hartford Avenue, Bellingham MA 2019","barnett@hotmail.com","Pattie Darsey"
"700 Oak Street, Brockton MA 2301","sbmrjbr@sbcglobal.net","Cammie Knoles"
"66-4 Parkhurst Rd, Chelmsford MA 1824","mastinfo@sbcglobal.net","Evia Fallen"
"591 Memorial Dr, Chicopee MA 1020","carcus@aol.com","Soo Sanfilippo"
```

or any other common file format. Both of the above can be understood by MS-Excel for example.

Just to show the minimal changes required, to get what you actually asked for (again, don't do it!) would be:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS  = " "
    ofmt = "%s%s"
    numFiles = ARGC - 1
}
FNR == 1 {
    fileNr++
}
{
    gsub(/[[:space:]^]+/,"^")
    gsub(/^\^|\^$/,"")
    val[FNR,ARGIND] = $0
}
fileNr == numFiles {
    for (i=1; i<=numFiles; i++) {
        printf ofmt, val[FNR,i], (i<numFiles ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2 file3
777^Brockton^Avenue,^Abington^MA^2351 madanm@comcast.net Manual^Ordway
30^Memorial^Drive,^Avon^MA^2322 skajan@verizon.net Yuonne^Cajigas
250^Hartford^Avenue,^Bellingham^MA^2019 barnett@hotmail.com Pattie^Darsey
700^Oak^Street,^Brockton^MA^2301 sbmrjbr@sbcglobal.net Cammie^Knoles
66-4^Parkhurst^Rd,^Chelmsford^MA^1824 mastinfo@sbcglobal.net Evia^Fallen
591^Memorial^Dr,^Chicopee^MA^1020 carcus@aol.com Soo^Sanfilippo
```

Answer (score 0):

Separators are not always spaces. So basically your first command does not remove the delimiter, it changes it to `^`

This command works as well:

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS='^' file > newfile
```

Sed would be better for this:

```
sed 's/ /^/g' file > newfile
```

For the second command, paste uses tab delimiter by default but you can change that. 
You want spaces, use space as `-d` option. :

```
paste -d" " file* > newfile
```

Keep in mind that you can chose any delimiter you want to read or write csv (it is not what its name suggests). If your input files use space delimiters, you can use comma delimiter for the paste command and that's it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was over complicating it. I just realised how easy I could have had it.

Comment: `awk '{$1=$1}1'` can be shortened to just `awk '$1=$1'`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou That would fail for empty record and 0

Comment: To be clear, `sed 's/ /^/g' file` != `awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS='^' file`. Consider both when tabs or multiple contiguous spaces or leading/trailing blanks exist in the input.